# Preciso fazer uma função que passada uma matriz n * m , seja transformada em um vetor unidimesional de tam n *m

Tags: c, ponteiro, matriz

```
int* Vetor_Unidim(int **matriz, int n, int m){

    int *vetor = (int*)malloc((n*m)*sizeof(int));
    int *p;
    p = *matriz;
    int tam = n*m;
    int i;

   for(i = 0; i<n; i++){
    p = matriz[i];      
    for(j= 0; j<m ; j++, p++){
    vetor[k]= *p;
    k++;
            }
    }
    return vetor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa de nenhum ponteiro auxiliar para converter a matriz, veja só:

```
int * Vetor_Unidim( int ** matriz, int m, int n )
{
    int i, x, y;
    int * vetor = (int*) malloc( n * m * sizeof(int) );

     for( x = 0, i = 0; x < m; x++ )
        for( y = 0; y < n; y++ )
            vetor[i++] = matriz[x][y];

    return vetor;
}
```

Comment: Entendi seu código, mas na hora de compilar ele tá dando erro.

Comment: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: Para resolver esse erro, falta colocar o _cast_ na frente do `malloc()`: `(int*)malloc( n * m * sizeof(int) );`

Comment: @RamilsonSilva: Corrigido!

Answer (score 0):

pelo que eu intendo na sua questao voce quer pegar isso Vetor[1][1] e passar para isso vetor[1*1], sendo assim:

```
int n = 0;
int vet[3][3];
int vetB[9];    

for(int x=0;x<3;x++){
   for(int y=0;y<3;y++){
      vet[x][y] = valor;
   }
}

for(x=0;x<3;x++){
   for(y=0;y<3;y++){
      vet[n] = vet[x][y];
      n++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Na verdade é uma função que recebe uma matriz

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* copiamatrizparavetor
 * Recebe a matriz, as dimensoes (m = altura, n = largura)
 * e devolve o vetor-alvo, de tamanho m x n.
 */
void copiamatrizparavetor(int** matriz, int m, int n, int* vetornovo)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            vetornovo[i * n + j] = matriz[i][j];
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int m, n;

    // Entro as dimensoes da matriz e do vetor.
    // m e a altura, n e a largura.
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);

    if (m > 0 && n > 0)
    {
        // Declaro aqui a matriz e o vetor.
        int matriz[m][n], vetor[m * n];

        // Entro os valores da matriz.
        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
                scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);

        // Copio o conteudo da matriz para o vetor.
        copiamatrizparavetor(matriz, m, n, vetor);

        // Imprimo o vetor.
        for (int k = 0; k < m * n; ++k)
        {
            // Imprimo o espaco, delimitador de coordenadas do vetor.
            if (k > 0)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }

            // Imprimo a coordenada atual do vetor.
            printf("%d", vetor[k]);

            if (k % n == 0)
            {
                // Quebro a linha para formatar o vetor em 
                // formato de matriz.
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        // Quebro a linha no final do processamento, para
        // deixar mais legivel.
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```